# Cannot get attribute value from <a> tag when <img> is an element of it

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html, lightning-design-system

I'm facing a wierd UI issue when I use-

```
<a href="www.someLink.com" onclick="c.controllerFunction" data-attriVal="abc">
        <img src="resource/image.PNG"/>
</a>
```

In my lightning controller, after image click I'm not able to get the **attriVal** by using-
Event.target.getAttribute('data-aatriVal');

But the same I'm getting when I replace the  tag with some text value-

```
<a href="www.someLink.com" onclick="c.controllerFunction" data-attriVal="abc">
        SOME TEXT VALUE
</a>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 10):

Due to event bubbling, when you click on the `img` tag anchor tag's `onclick` event is being fired. As a result,

**event.target** => points to the element where the click originated which is the `<img/>`. So doing `event.target.getAttribute("data-attriVal")` will return **null**

**event.currentTarget** => points to the element which registered and called the click event's function (i.e `<a />`). So doing `event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-attriVal")` will return **abc**

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/misteroneill/kmn4A/3/).